# Is female an acceptable term to describe a woman?

Tags: single-word-requests

I sometimes hear people refer a woman as a "female", but some people say it's derogatory to call a woman a "female". Is it acceptable to call a woman a "female"?

P.S I'm not a native English speaker

Comment: In what context?

Comment: For referring to a woman: "I met a female who was very intelligent."

Comment: Could you [edit that context into the original question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/430853/edit)? You've used the `meaning-in-context` tag,  but haven't given any in the question. How acceptable 'female' is should be evaluated on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: It is difficult to see how "there is a shortage of female pilots in the airline industry" is derogatory.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yeah, you've heard it correct. Refering to women as a plain "female" is considered derogatory, non-sensitive and rude in most parts of the English-speaking world, also in India.

If you want to talk about women unknown to you then you can say for eg. : "Today, I stumbled upon a lady near my Office who asked me the directions to the City Center". But avoid using "female" instead.

Consider this: English is a language of exceptions. You'll come across more such 'terms' which are not used in public and should be avoided at all costs.

[this link might help you](http://www.slate.com/blogs/lexicon_valley/2016/02/18/when_you_should_use_female_woman_or_lady_as_an_adjective_a_guide.html) . Please go through it patiently. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, many people will consider it rude to refer to a woman as *a female*, although I do notice people doing it. Interestingly, I don't hear *men* referred to as *males* as often...

Now what makes it offensive? We commonly use *male* and *female* when referring to *animals*, but for *humans* we have a plethora of other words like *man/woman*, *gent(leman)/lady*, etc.

> Is that dog in there a male? No it's a female.
>
> Is the patient a man? No, it's a woman.

Note that in the first example, we could have used the word *bitch*, which after all refers to a female dog. Clearly, it's not uncommon to use animal designations to describe humans in unpleasant ways. In general that is considered rude, though.

So in short, if you don't want to give the impression you treat a woman like an animal, use human-specific words when referring to her.